# Drools 6 & jBPM 6 how to integrate?

Tags: java, jboss, workflow, drools, jbpm

I would like to make an application which allows user to define what will happens after specific rule or rules occures. I wonder if i should make my own GUI or if i can use something "built-in" in Drools or jBPM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new KIE-Workbench which basically provides you the authoring environment for rules and then extend it if you want to show some domain specific results. The KIE Workbench was built with the idea that every business will require some domain specific screens and for that reason is it easy to extend.